# Unable to check-out an excel sheet from a document library in SharePoint 2010 Standard

Tags: 2010, excel, check-out

I have a document library under my SharePoint 2010 Standard site. We are uploading Excel files to this document library to be updated by multiple users (Using Check-in/Check-out). We are using IE9 as our browser for check-in and checkout.

Like other users I was able to checkout the Excel files (I have MS Office 2007 on my client machine) and upload them again after updating.

But one day, I and another user found that SharePoint is not allowing us to checkout the file. It gives the following message when clicking on the check-out item using the context menu:

> This document could not be checked out. You may not have permission to check out the document or it is already checked out or locked for editing by another user.

Immediately after the above message, i get following message,

> The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit this document.

1. I have verified that the document in question is not checkout by any other user.
2. The same message is appearing for every document in this library.
3. I have tried uploading a document in another library and I was unable to check-out that also.
4. I am able to checkout the same document - if I use Chrome as my browser.

Comment: Any recent updates applied to your server?

Comment: David, as per my knowledge no updates are applied on the server. Moreover, there are other users who are having same permissions on the document library and are able to perform the editing, check-in and checkout operations normally.

Comment: Check to see if your minor version number is 0.511 if so create a major version and you should be able to check out then...

Comment: Check if Office Document Cache Handler Add-On is Enabled in IE settings